# How to load page fragments from another file and display it using jQuery load()function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#items').load("<?php echo site_url('home/new_items'); ?>");
});
```

Using jQuery I am able to display a whole page, that 'home/new_items' calls using the above code but how do I only display parts of the file? 
[$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
In the example it shows this is possible, so how do I use this in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot insert php code by java script code.

Also using jQuery load, you can just load file from directory without any php help.

Hint: use

```
$(function(){/*your code*/});
```

If you are using jQuery

Comment: I don't think you understand, this isn't just a PHP code, it's my site URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display parts of page, however you need either to:

- parse page and cut only part which you need to show

or

- prepare part from server side (PHP), you could make AJAX call with parameters

> $('#result').load('ajax/test.php?part=some_special_part_of_page');